# How can count the number of times a user enter password wrong using authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic for authentication. I want to redirect the user to a contact form if they are still having trouble logging in so they can contact me after a few try.

```
class MySiteController < ApplicationController
  before_filter  :authenticate
  def index
  end
  protected

  def authenticate
    count = 0
    authenticate = authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == 'username' && password == 'password'
      count += 1
      if count == 3
         break
      end
    end
    if authenticate == false
      redirect_to contact_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered using a session variable to count incorrect logins?  That way it's easier to dump

Comment: The `count` variable is not persisted so every time you hit controller you are setting it to 1 and exiting.